# Replace ubuntu boot menu (iMac)

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2, dual-boot, mac

I have a 21.5" iMac (Intel based), and I recently installed Ubuntu on a 90GB partition. After I installed Ubuntu, I noticed that whenever i boot my machine I get GRUB where I can select my OS (Mac or Ubuntu). GRUB came after I installed Ubuntu and it is using the Ubuntu color scheme, so I know it relates to Ubuntu.

Problem is, that when I am in GRUB my apple wireless keyboard is not working, and after 10 seconds Ubuntu gets auto-selected, and I can not boot into Mac OS X without a USB keyboard.

So I wondered if it is possible to solve this problem, and if not - how can i replace GRUB to a mac boot menu or maybe to rEFIt? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Regarding the keyboard: what kind is it? Grub2 has modules to control USB devices directly so it might be fixable.

Comment: You are right, this is GRUB - I did not know that haha :). My Keyboard is a standard apple wireless Bluetooth keyboard, without a numpad. On the back it says model number: A1314.

Comment: Hmmm can not find any link to a BT Keyboard and a fix for it so you can use it during boot :( sorry.

Comment: @Rinzwind what do you mean? And if it is not possible, do you know how can I replace GRUB?